# SQS-style distributed delay queue, but outside of AWS?

Tags: apache-kafka, message-queue, amazon-sqs, producer-consumer, distributed-system

I'm looking for a distributed queueing system that supports delayed message delivery, i.e. where consumers would receive a message only after a specified delay from when the producer sent it. [SQS](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/) is the system I'm most familiar with (particularly the [visibility timeout](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-visibility-timeout.html) feature), but I'm in an environment where AWS is off limits.

I see a few options right now, but none of them are very appetizing:

- I'm less familiar with [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) and its [TTL feature](http://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html), but if push comes
  to shove I might be able to cobble together out of this.
- There's the possibility of using a job scheduler instead of a message queue, but that seems like a pretty bad impedance mismatch for my situation.
- I could take the database-as-queue approach, but there's all sorts of reasons I don't want to do that.

So my question is this: is there a queueing system that supports delayed delivery out of the box without having to layer a bunch of application logic on top to make it work?

Comment: We struggle with the same problem as you. As we have hundreds of messages waiting for execution, the polling and re-queuing starts to become a real pain. Did you find a solution for your problem?

Comment: Not yet, unfortunately. If I find a solution, I'll definitely post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Recent Kafka versions have by default a timestamp on each message, and you can use that to create an artificially delayed stream.

Simply create a KafkaConsumer, and in the poll loop, check if the timestamp is at least `n` seconds old. If it is, pause the loop for a few seconds (I've used 5 seconds before pretty effectively, but even one second will work for very high volume topics), and continue processing as normal.  This will effectively pause the consumer until the next record to process is "ready" (i.e., old enough), and it will keep throttling itself, always keeping it `n` seconds away from real-time.

More info from the Javadoc on the `KafkaConsumer`:

https://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/ConsumerRecord.html#timestamp--